# Converting <select></option> in <a></a> links (Ajax)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

My ajax script is working fine with this:

```
<head>
<script>
function showUser(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","y.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
</head>

<select  onchange="showUser(this.value)">
  <option value="">Select a person:</option>
  <option value="1">Peter Griffin</option>
  <option value="2">Lois Griffin</option>
  <option value="3">Joseph Swanson</option>
  <option value="4">Glenn Quagmire</option>
  <option value="5">Glenn Quagmire</option>
  </select>
```

But, instead of `<select><option>`I want to convert it into link.

But the ajax script do not work, when I do this:

```
<div onchange="showUser(this.value)">
<a value="1" href="">1</a>
<a value="2" href="">2</a>
<a value="3" href="">3</a>
</div>
```

How to change them? I need them for pagination.

Comment: `<div onchange="showUser(this.value)">` < that is never going to work; I think you'll be better off stating what you *actually* want to achieve rather than what you *think* you want to achieve: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and dirty hack:

```
<div>
<a href="javascript:void(showUser(1));">Peter Griffin</a>
<a href="javascript:void(showUser(2));">Lois Griffin</a>
<a href="javascript:void(showUser(3));">Joseph Swanson</a>
<a href="javascript:void(showUser(4));">Glenn Quagmire</a>
...
</div>
```

---

For a more elegant solution (*progressive enhancement* with HTML5 and jQuery) - assuming there's a `profile.php` page (or similar) that can actually be accessed when JavaScript is disabled.

You can still use this with an empty `href` if there's no profile page; it *is* cleaner - but, like the initial hack, it won't work if JS is disabled.

```
<head>
...

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#user_filter > a").each(function() {
        $(this).click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            showUser($(this).attr("data-user-id"));
        });
    });
});
</script>

...
</head>
<body>
...

<div id="user_filter">
<a href="/link/to/profile.php?user=1" data-user-id="1">Peter Griffin</a>
<a href="/link/to/profile.php?user=2" data-user-id="2">Lois Griffin</a>
<a href="/link/to/profile.php?user=3" data-user-id="3">Joseph Swanson</a>
<a href="/link/to/profile.php?user=4" data-user-id="4">Glenn Quagmire</a>
...
</div>

...
</body>
```

Comment: Working. Btw, i want to add "?tag1=name" at the end of the url, how to do this, in your code?

Comment: You're not actually changing the URL if you're using Ajax to update the `.innerHTML` of an element... that's kinda the point.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `onchange` and can add below HTML & JQuery code. Now that we have div and a tags, we should use `click()` event.

```js
$(".selectOptions a").on('click', function() {
  alert('You clicked on: ' + $(this).attr('value'));
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selectOptions">
  <a value="1" href="">1</a>
  <a value="2" href="">2</a>
  <a value="3" href="">3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: ... what's the point? `<a>` already has a click event, the `href` - it doesn't have a `value`; you're over-complicating matters. If it's for pagination via Ajax you can just hijack the `href` attributes - that way if JS isn't working for whatever reason the whole thing degrades gracefully.

Comment: Well, there is a value attribute which I believe he is gonna use. I am answering based on questions requirement. If given a chance, will definitely change the HTML to achieve this.

Comment: Yeah, I will use href="" for more filters like tags. 

@MilanChheda I edited my question and added the ajax script. Can you tell me, where to add your Jquery script in it? Thanks a lot bro

Comment: Just because the OP has stuck a `value` attribute on a `<a>` tag - doesn't mean it actually exists... `<a>` has *no* `value` attribute.

Comment: @RavinaSharma - You need to add it in your JS.

Comment: Like this? http://prntscr.com/fgxnfy

Sorry, i do not know JS much till now. I am still learning

Comment: I have added a running script, you can modify it to your needs. You need to add your code inside the `function()`

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="paging">
                <a value="1" href="#" >1</a>
                <a value="2" href="#" >2</a>
                <a value="3" href="#" >3</a>
            </div>
     <script>
        $('.paging').find('a').click(function () {
            alert($(this).attr("value"));
        });

        </script>
```